# Table data centering in the table row

Tags: wordpress, html-table

Ok so I have a few tables on a page and one of them is giving me trouble. It is the second table on the page The left column is how I want it, the other appears to be centering the data within the table row. I don't understand why, I don't think its CSS from the WordPress template because if I launch it as a raw HTML file in my browser it is doing the same thing. Here is the link to the resulting page with the tables (second table down): http://titanpropertymanagement.co/residents/utility-info/

I know this issue is probably super simple but I am still learning to code so I'm sure it's just missing a simple style tag. Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Here is the code for the second table giving me issues

```
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Water &amp; Trash Service</h2>
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                <h4>Water/Trash for Lafayette</h4>
                <h5><a href="http://bit.ly/18q8zsG" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Lafayette Utility Dept.</span></a> - (765) 807-1100</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline"><a href="http://www.titanmgmtgroup.com/uploads/2/3/9/1/23918042/lafayette_watersewer_application.pdf">Download Application Here</a>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h5>Lafayette Sanitation - (765) 807-1411</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://bit.ly/1as4CRr" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Request Trash/Recycle Bin</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h5>Waste Management - (800) 443-5646</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://bit.ly/17OzcDf" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Request Service Online</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td width="50%">
                <h4>Water/Trash For West Lafayette</h4>
                <h5><a href="http://bit.ly/16iR0qF" target="_blank"><span style="text-decoration: underline">American Water</span></a> - (800) 492-8373</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://bit.ly/1as4RMr" target="_blank">Request New Service Online</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <h5>W. Lafayette Sanitation - (765) 775-5242</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://bit.ly/H0lQyl" target="_blank">Request Service Online</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
tbody {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

to your stylesheet. This will override the browser's default styling of tbody, which is to vertically align the tbody to the middle (at least in Chrome).